# How to define a qreal literal

Tags: qt, literals

In the Qt docs it says that a `qreal` is a

> Typedef for double unless Qt is configured with the -qreal float option.

This basically means almost always `double` but `float` on ARM devices.

I want to use `qreal` literals however I don't know how to write them.

```
qreal someValue = calcFunc();
qreal min = qMin(someValue, 0.0);
```

Where `0.0` is a `double` literal and `0.0f` would be a `float` literal. On ARM this is a compile arror as there is no `qMin(float, double)` function.

I could write `static_cast<qreal>(0.0)` but this seems overly verbose.

So how do I define a `qreal` literal?

Comment: What's the problem with `qreal value=1.234`? The compiler should handle all conversion, no need for explicit cast.

Comment: @KarstenKoop I've modified the example code in the question to make the issue clearer.

Comment: You can define a C++11 user-defined literal that will return qreal.

Comment: @Velkan I am indeed using **c++11** how would I go about making sure that my literal matched the qreal type?

Comment: Define `qreal operator "" _qr(long double){...}`, then use `1.0_qr` in code: it will call that operator. I don't write a full answer because never used that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use C++11 [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal):

```
#include <QtCore>

constexpr qreal operator "" _qr(long double a){ return qreal(a); }

int main() {
   qreal a = 3.0_qr;
   Q_ASSERT(qMin(a, 4.0_qr) == a);
}
```

If they're not available on your platform, you can explicitly construct qreals when you need them:

```
using _qr  = qreal;

int main() {
   qreal a = _qr(3.0);
   Q_ASSERT(qMin(a, _qr(4.0)) == a);
}
```

Comment: `using _qr  = qreal;` is not valid as names starting with underscore are reserved in the global scope.

Comment: It could of course be moved out of the global namespace, since we’re `using` it anyway.